# Null pointer al logearse en una cuenta

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Cuando el usuario se logea en la app, y le da a su usuario sale este error, en cambio si buscas a otra persona antes y le das al Fragment de usuario, le queda la última persona que buscaste. No veo nada incorrecto aquí puede que el error venga de otro lado, pero no consigo localizarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la función donde da el error.

```
private void userInfo(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(profileid);
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (getContext() == null){
                return;
            }
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            Glide.with(getContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
            username.setText(user.getUsername());
            fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
            bio.setText(user.getBio());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

La interfaz está basada en la de Instagram y evidentemente cuando se pulsa en el usuario la idea es mostrar al usuario que está en la cuenta, no otros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He cambiado un valor de profileid, ahora mismo no da error pero sigue pasando lo mismo de que cuando le doy al usuario aparece el último que he buscado. Espero que esto sea útil.

```
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user, container, false);

    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
    profileid = prefs.getString("profileid", firebaseUser.getUid());


    image_profile = view.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
    posts = view.findViewById(R.id.posts);
    followers = view.findViewById(R.id.followers);
    following = view.findViewById(R.id.following);
    fullname = view.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
    bio = view.findViewById(R.id.bio);
    edit_profile = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
    username = view.findViewById(R.id.username);
    my_fotos = view.findViewById(R.id.my_fotos);
    saved_fotos = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_fotos);
    options = view.findViewById(R.id.options);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    myFotoAdapter = new MyFotoAdapter(getContext(), postList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myFotoAdapter);

    recyclerView_saves = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_save);
    recyclerView_saves.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManagers = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3);
    recyclerView_saves.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManagers);
    postList_saves = new ArrayList<>();
    myFotoAdapter_saves = new MyFotoAdapter(getContext(), postList_saves);
    recyclerView_saves.setAdapter(myFotoAdapter_saves);

    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView_saves.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    userInfo();
    getFollowers();
    getNrPosts();
    myFotos();
    mySaves();

    if (profileid.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
        edit_profile.setText("Edit Profile");
    } else {
        checkFollow();
        saved_fotos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    edit_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String btn = edit_profile.getText().toString();

            if (btn.equals("Edit Profile")){

                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), EditProfileActivity.class));

            } else if (btn.equals("follow")){

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("following").child(profileid).setValue(true);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(profileid)
                        .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                //addNotification();
            } else if (btn.equals("following")){

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                        .child("following").child(profileid).removeValue();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(profileid)
                        .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();

            }
        }
    });

  

    my_fotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView_saves.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    saved_fotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView_saves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


 

    return view;
}
```

Comment: debes colocar el log como texto, en una imagen es más dificil de leer. El error es que `dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)` está retornando `null`, muy probablemente debido a que la variable `profileid` tiene un valor erroneo. Eso es todo lo que podemos decirte con la poca información que das

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error como bien aportaron era debido a la variable profileid, pero venía de otra activity, en la cual la había escrito mal y eso producía un error más adelante.